# How to deduce wsdl for web service under tomcat

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I developed a ws using netbeans using annotations:

```
@WebService MyWS()
public class MyWS {
  @WebMethod(operationName="MyWebMethod")
  public MyWebMethod(@WebParam(name="str") StringHolder str){
    ...
  }
}
```

The applicaction's context root is /WSTests

Based on this information how can I deduce what's the .wsdl associated with my project to test it with - for instance - soapui ?

Something like http://localhost:8080/WStests/xxxx/yyyy.wsdl

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it...

It's

Pointing soapUI to:

http://localhost:8080/WSTests/MyWS?wsdl

I get a list of it's web methods.